# Word guessing game in C

Tags: c

I am having some issues writing a program. The program is essentially the word guessing game hangman. I have the store a word, and the user gets however many chances to guess the word. I'm having trouble getting the game to loop correctly and end when the number of guesses has been used up. Also, I made a second array with, the same size as the array with my word, but this array is filled with dashes. If a letter is correctly guessed, I need the correct letter to show up around the dashes. If somebody can help, I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // Input and output operations
#include <stdlib.h>  // General purpose functions

int main(void)
{
   FILE*fp;          // File pointer variable
   fp = fopen("Quiz 6", "w");

   int numTries, tries, i;  // Declaration of variables
   char guess;
   char myWord [6] = {'a','p','p','l','e','\0'};  // Initialization of variables
   char dashedArray [6] = {'-','-','-','-','-','-'};

   numTries = 0;
   i=0;
   tries = 0;

   printf("\nLet's play a game! The objective of the game is to guess my secret word. You will have
          five chances to guess.\n");
   printf("\nLet's get started!\n");
   printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
   scanf("%c", &guess);

   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      numTries = numTries +1;
      if (guess == myWord [0])
      {
         printf("\n %c----", myWord [0]);
         printf("\nGood Guess!\n");
         printf("\nPlease guess another letter: ");
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
      }

      if ( guess == myWord [1] && myWord [1] )
      {
         printf("\n-%c%c--", myWord [1], myWord [1]);
         printf("\nGood Guess!\n");
         printf("\nPlease guess another letter: ");
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
      }

      if ( guess == myWord [3] )
      {
         printf("\n---%c-", myWord [3]);
         printf("\nGood Guess!\n");
         printf("\nPlease guess another letter: ");
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
      }

      if ( guess == myWord [4] )
      {
         printf("\n----%c", myWord [4]);
         printf("\nGood Guess!\n");
         printf("\nPlease guess another letter: ");
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
      }

      if ( if word is completed and guessed correctly )
      {
         printf("\nCongrats! You guessed the secret word!\n");
      }

      else if ( guess != myWord )
      {
         printf("\nSorry. That is not a correct letter. Please guess again:\n");
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need?

Comment: Yep, the only question mark (?) on this page is @DavidSchwartz's ...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: i think he asked help with his code. which he has mentioned is not working properly

Comment: He may want to look into ncurses library for some help with having the letter appear if guessed correctly and in keeping with the linux teachings read the man http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html if you don't know what it is.

Comment: @ralph Right, but *what* help? Does he need help fixing compiler errors? Does he need help figuring out the algorithm to use? Does his code do the wrong thing? If so, what is he expecting it to do? What is he observing?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: true. he should have been clearer with his question

Answer (score 2):

you have several issues with your code. i will try to point them out

```
numTries = numTries + 1;
```

you are using this variable, incrementing it in every iteration, but not using it anywhere.

```
if (guess == myWord [0])
{
   printf("\n %c----", myWord [0]);
   printf("\nGood Guess!\n");
   printf("\nPlease guess another letter: ");
   scanf(" %c", &guess);
}
```

you are comparing the guessed character with different characters of the word, but not remembering in anyway which letters or how many letters have been correctly guessed. ( maybe use a flag variable for this)

```
if ( if word is completed and guessed correctly )
{
   printf("\nCongrats! You guessed the secret word!\n");
}
```

the above if loop makes no sense in c language

```
else if ( guess != myWord )
{
   printf("\nSorry. That is not a correct letter. Please guess again:\n");
   scanf(" %c", &guess);
}
```

the above elseif statement compares a character variable with an array's base address

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic skeleton that you want your program to have. It doesn't work perfectly (I won't even guarantee that it compiles), but it should give you ideas on how you can improve your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char guess, newline;
    char myWord [6] = {'a','p','p','l','e','\0'};               // Initialization of variables
    char dashedArray [6] = {'-','-','-','-','-','\0'};
    int totalTries = 5;
    int currentTries = 0;
    int i, j;

    printf("\nLet's play a game! The objective of the game is to guess my secret word. You will have five chances to guess.\n");
    printf("\nLet's get started!\n");

    for (i=0; i<totalTries; i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
        scanf("%c\n", &guess);

        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            if (guess == myWord[j])
                dashedArray[j] = guess;
        }

        printf("Result: %s", dashedArray);

    }

    printf("You lose.");
}
```